# Detect click on activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android App, I've got and transparent activity as Facebook : http://screenshots.fr.sftcdn.net/fr/scrn/87000/87052/facebook-09-300x535.jpg

I want to detect when the user clicks when the content is transparent.

Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: What is the transparent activity that you are refering to?

Comment: hard to understand what's your question, comment your question in french.

Comment: It looks like just a `PopupWindow` or something similar with a `ListView`. Do you want to be able to click on what's behind that little window? If so, to close it, select something, etc...?

Comment: Look at the picture : there is the content of the popup and when you click outside, the popup is closed.